# Python Discord Bot TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Tags: python, discord, bots

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 25, in 
bot = discord.Client(interactions.Client(token=""),command_prefix='$' , intents=intents,)
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

I have a discord bot that uses both slash commands, and @bot.event on_message $ prefix commands using if message content == "", as of recently, it started showing a type error, Im very stumped over this, I removed the file path and token from the error message to protect privacy

```
print("starting... ")

import requests
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
import discord.ext.tasks
import python_weather
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import random
import math
import subprocess
import time
import interactions
import os



print("imports sucessful")

now = datetime.now()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = discord.Client(interactions.Client(token=""),command_prefix='$' , intents=intents,)
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the whole code.

Comment: Alright its been changed, i cant show all of it but, i can show you the section where the error took place

Comment: Try putting `intents` second and `command_prefix` third.

Comment: putting intents second and command_prefix third still shows the same error

Comment: The post has been updated so you guys can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, this is because you passed in `interactions.Client(token="")` as the first parameter of the [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) constructor, which is wrong.

To enable a command to be used with the `$` prefix and as a slash command, create a [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot), and register a [`HybridCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.HybridCommand) with the [`@commands.Bot.hybrid_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.hybrid_command) decorator.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@bot.hybrid_command(name="say", description="say something", scope=...)
async def say(ctx, text: string):
    await ctx.send(text)
```

Comment: doing so still shows the same error

Comment: if it helps this is the command format im using, `@bot.hybrid_command(
     name="say",
     description="say something",
     #scope=the_id_of_your_guild,
     options = [
         interactions.Option(
             name="text",
             description="What you want to say",
             type=interactions.OptionType.STRING,
             required=True,
        ),
    ],
)
async def say(ctx: interactions.CommandContext, text: str):
    await ctx.send(f"{text}")

Comment: Hybrid commands are supposed to take [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) as input. Check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.hybrid_command) and my answer.

Comment: The post has been updated, so you can understand it better

Comment: Based on your post, you created a [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) object directly which you should not do in this case! Please copy-paste my code directly and remove your old code.